# How to create a secure express.js + mongodb user authentication system

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am in the following situation at the moment:
I have created a user authentication system using the following technologies:
expressjs (using sessions and cookies) 
mysql (to keep the user name and the password)
mongodb for persistent session storage

The aim is to create system that will store a userid in a cookie, and based on that allow access or not.

First question. If I understand correctly how the sessions work, is that every time a user visits my website (logged in or not), she/he will create a new session id using the express session mechanism which is going to be stored in req.sessionID.

The problem now. On the login page:
User enters a user name/password.
I make a request to mysql server, confirm both username/password. Now, from the examples I have found online, a solution to do a simple user authentication is to do something like this:
req.session.user=username
Then later on check if the req.session.user is set, and based on that allow access to the user etc.
However, for my website, the user's username, is the user's email. Is it safe to store in a cookie value amd in plain text the user's details, even if it is for authentication purposes?

What other options are available? Can I encrypt the username before storing in the database with bcrypt, and use that?

Thanks in advance.

A

Comment: Generate a session ID that you assign to the cookie. On the backend you can track the session ID and expire it whenever you want.  If the session ID doesn't match what your backend stores, they aren't authenticated.  If you just go on the username or email, what's to keep someone from crafting a session response with someone elses username and is now authenticated as them? Your server has no idea what is and isn't valid

Comment: Your question is too broad, but have a look at passeport.js and local-strategy, it will handle these stuff for you, better than you would.

Comment: @mpm - I had a look at passport, but I found better to implement something simpler of myself, also it would help me understand certain concepts.

Comment: @devshorts - Ok, I get the point. One more thing. Do I need to associate the generated sessionID with each user at the backend? So at each request do I validate that the sessionID is just a valid one, or do I need a key-value store, that contains the user name - sessionID.

Comment: you should have a key value store, where the key is the sessionID and the value is any related metadata you want for that user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set you session cookie options to be httpOnly and pass long enough string to secret.
2. Your req object has not only sessionID property but also session object. This object is stored in Mongo (or whatever session storage you pass to express) and it's contents is not available for your clients. So you can securely store whatever info you want here.

Behind the scenes Express checks that session key (the only part of the session available to the client, you can prove this checking resources tab of Chrome devtools) matches current session. If someone tries to forge session key Express will notice this. Actually, Express uses Connect middleware, so you may want to skim this for more details http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html

Comment: THanks for the answer. So if I understand it correctly, connect.sid has the same value as in the req.session, which express uses to make sure that the session is not tampered. But req.session is not available in the client. So as you said, i can store safely there something like req.session.user. However isn't it safer, in req.session.user to store something like an id, rather than the user email, username or something like that?

Comment: Well, if someone gains access to the req.session object, chances are that he will be able to find missing information by id you generously store in session. So i believe this will not provide any addition safety but rather force you to manually pull email from DB.  However i'm not a security guru, so this is only how i think of it.